# using C++11 templates to generate multiple versions of an algorithm

Tags: c++11, templates

Say I'm making a general-purpose collection of some sort, and there are 4-5 points where a user might want to choose implementation A or B.  For instance:

- homogenous or heterogenous
- do we maintain a count of the contained objects, which is slower
- do we have it be thread-safe or not

I could just make 16 or 32 implementations, with each combination of features, but obviously this won't be easy to write or maintain.

I could pass in boolean flags to the constructor, that the class could check before doing certain operations.  However, the compiler doesn't "know" what those arguments were so has to check them every time, and just checking enough boolean flags itself imposes a performance penalty.

So I'm wondering if template arguments can somehow be used so that at compile time the compiler sees `if (false)` or `if (true)` and therefore can completely optimize out the condition test, and if false, the conditional code.  I've only found examples of templates as types, however, not as compile-time constants.

The main goal would be to utterly eliminate those calls to lock mutexes, increment and decrement counters, and so on, but additionally, if there's some way to actually remove the mutex or counters from the object structure as well that's be truly optimal.

Comment: `if constexpr` was introduced in C++17. Template specialization was the only choice before that.

Comment: @bipll template specialization?  Would that apply here?

Answer (score 1):

Conditional computation before 17 was mostly about template specialization. Either specializing the function itself

```cpp
template<> void f<int>(int) {
    std::cout << "Locking an int...\n";
    std::cout << "Unlocking an int...\n";
}

template<> void f<std::mutex>(std::mutex &m) {
    m.lock();
    m.unlock();
}
```

But this actually creates a rather branchy code (in your case I suspect), so a more sound alternative would be to extract all the dependent, type-specific, parts into static interface and define a static implementation of it for a particular concrete type:

```cpp
template<class T> struct lock_traits;  // interface

template<> struct lock_traits<int> {
    void lock(int &) { std::cout << "Locking an int...\n"; }
    void unlock(int &) { std::cout << "Unlocking an int...\n"; }
};

template<> struct lock_traits<std::mutex> {
    void lock(std::mutex &m) { m.lock(); }
    void unlock(std::mutex &m) { m.unlock(); }
};

template<class T> void f(T &t) {
    lock_traits<T>::lock(t);
    lock_traits<T>::unlock(t);
}
```

In C++17 `if constrexpr` was finally introduced, now not all branches do have to compile in all circumstances.

```
template<class T> void f(T &t) {
    if constexpr<std::is_same_v<T, std::mutex>> {
        t.lock();
    }
    else if constexpr<std::is_same_v<T, int>> {
        std::cout << "Locking an int...\n";
    }

    if constexpr<std::is_same_v<T, std::mutex>> {
        t.unlock();
    }
    // forgot to unlock an int here :(
}
```

Comment: OK, but what if I'm happy to have the code read `if (true)` and simply trust the compiler optimizations to remove it?   The code you're showing is very interesting, but removing code in an un-optimized build isn't a priority...

Comment: Well, if you're sure it compiles. You cannot truly lock an int, so `if(std::is_same_v<T, std::mutex>) t.lock();` wouldn't compile when `T` is `int`, but `if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, std::mutex>) t.lock();` will.